# All downloads throttled at 125 kbps

Tags: download, bittorrent, speed, steam, throttling

I have been trying to download a game through steam, but i have observed that download speed i get is only upto 125kbps. Whenever i try to download something through at torrent client like µTorrent , i get 5mbps+ speeds. I have check my internet speed on fast.com, and speedtest.net . I get 30Mbps+ most of the time. Also whenever i try to download something through chrome, or any other software updates, i only get 100 to 125kbps speed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please try a download with wget from the command line as illustrated at https://www.marksanborn.net/howto/using-wget-to-download-youtube-videos/ and advise the result.

Comment: Sounds like you have configured Steam to throttle the download.  Can you provide us your Steam settings pertaining to downloads?

Comment: Can you run http://dslreports.com/speedtest and post a link to your results page with your bufferbloat grade? It would be interesting to know if you have a bufferbloat problem going on. Bufferbloat doesn't usually cause slow downloads, but it could do so, in theory, if your upstream was congested and your download client's TCP Acks were taking forever to get back to the server. (If dslreports' speed test is not supported where you are, fast.com has ways to show your latency under load if you click on the advanced options after a test.)